# How to programmatically reset Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Students in the class I'm TAing are wondering if there is a way to programmatically reset the Gazebo simulation so they can debug their projects faster. I could benefit from this too :). A couple of them said that they looked through the documentation and couldn't find anything in the Gazebo API.

Is it possible to programmatically reset a Gazebo simulation?

thanks,

--ben

[www.meam620.info](http://www.meam620.info)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9165/how-to-programmatically-reset-gazebo/) by [ben](https://answers.ros.org/users/33/ben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 674 on 2011-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

here's the [ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4819) and the potential candidate patch

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Besides the drop down menu file--> reset through the gazebo gui, there isn't a way right now, but it should be easy to add a ros service call for resetting the world.
Can you please ticket me on this?
Thanks,
John

---

Originally posted by [john](https://answers.ros.org/users/16/john/) with karma: 86 on 2011-02-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1